# How to make save shortcut like ctrl+s?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have such code

```
JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem(new MenuItemAction("Save", null, KeyEvent.VK_S, (e) -> saveFile()));
        saveMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

Where i just add a menu item with shortcut as accelerator. The problem is that i cannot trigger this action without firstly choosing its parent menu. So how to add such shortcut to the hole frame and to this menu as well?

Comment: What kind of menu are you working with? Is it a normal JMenu (anchored below the titlebar) or is it a popup menu?

Comment: Works fine for me (ie. the Action is invoked, but the menu is not displayed). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information. If you need more help post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. Chances are while creating the MRE you will find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about application/global-scope for that key-event, so you may add the key-event to the root pane keys mapping.

For example, during form initialization, something like following:

```java
this.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {//this, is a JFrame
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //call the related ctrl + s func
            }
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW );
```